Cx_freeze, rename "lib" dir with something else, can it be done?
Currently I generate python exe with cx freeze, using this setup:
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["pyarmor", "os", "sys", "hashlib", "json", "time", "logging", "subprocess", "traceback", "paramiko", "PyQt5"],
    "excludes": [],
    "include_files": [("dist/pyarmor_runtime_000000", "dist/pyarmor_runtime_000000")]
}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

# Define the executable
executables = [
    Executable("dist/patcher-source.py", base=base, target_name="Awakening2-Patcher.exe", icon='patcher-icon.ico')
]

setup(
    name="Awakening2-Patcher",
    version="1.0",
    description="Auto Patcher for Awakening2",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executables
)

Currently in a tricky situation bcs cx freeze is the only exe patcher that is not flagged as virus and i m stuck with it
And second problem is the lib directory, which conflicts with lib dir in my app client, which has shared .pyc's but from different versions
Is there a way to change the lib dir name on cx freeze part?

Help a brother out, been wasting so much time on this damn patcher thing, and just to not test it till now and found out in cooked and can't really use it :(
